# Cannot locate file location

Tags: java

I'm trying to scan a text file. Yes, I know... this is simple. I've been trying to locate the path of my text file and nothing works, it gives me a NoSuchFileException

```
for (String line :  Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/com/panda/anagramsolver/handling/word_list.txt"))) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The file I'm trying to scan is located at **com.panda.anagramsolver.handling.word_list.txt**. I know this question will get a lot of downvotes, I couldn't elaborate my question enough to find it on google. In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path starts with a `/`. So unless you mean to search inside a directory named `com` in your root directory, you will fail to locate the file.

You might want to try executing something like `System.out.println(new File("."))` to find the location at which the program is executed, and then build up a relative path from that location. But at a more fundamental level, if the program is intended to work with that file always (i.e., if the file is a resource for the program), you might want to turn to [Class#getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). This [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077352/java-se/smartly-load-your-properties.html) is to a tutorial.